# My php mail function is sending blank messages

Tags: php, email, sendmail

So as the title states I receive blank emails from my contact form. The php code is below. I've checked the value of $msg and it appears correctly, I've also googled a ton and I can't find anything standard cause that apply to me.

```
<?php
main();

function main() {
    $posted = setVariables();
    $msg = setMessage($posted);
    $result = sendMail($msg);
    userFeedback($result);
}

function setVariables() {
    $name;
    if (isset($_POST['name'])){
        $name=$_POST['name'];
        if ($name == null) {
            $name = "ERROR - name is null";
        }
    }

    $email;
    if (isset($_POST['email'])){
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        if ($email == null) {
            $email = "ERROR - email is null";
        }
    }

    $enquiry;
    if (isset($_POST['enquiry'])){
        $enquiry=$_POST['enquiry'];
        if ($enquiry == null) {
            $enquiry = "ERROR - enquiry is null";
        }
    }

    $message;
    if (isset($_POST['message'])){
        $message=$_POST['message'];
        if ($message == null) {
            $message = "ERROR - message is null";
        }
    }

    $posted = array($name,$email,$enquiry,$message);
    return $posted;
}

function setMessage($posted) {
    $msg = "Name: " . $posted[0] . "\r\nEmail: " . $posted[1] . "\r\nEnquiry: " . $posted[2] . "\r\nMessage: " . $posted[3];
    $msg = wordwrap($msg,70);
    $msg = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Message']));
    return $msg;
}

function sendMail($msg) {
    $result = mail("social@georgeappleton.co.uk","Contact From Portfolio",$msg, "From: <info@yourdomain.co.uk>");
    return $result;
}

function userFeedback($result) {
    if ($result == false) {
        echo "Message failed to send, please inform me through my email address. social@georgeappleton.co.uk";
    } else {
        echo "Message Sent!<br/><br/>Returning you to <a href='http://www.georgeappleton.co.uk'>georgeappleton.co.uk</a> in 5 seconds";
    }
    echo "<script>setTimeout(function() {window.location = 'http://www.georgeappleton.co.uk';},5000);</script>";
}
?>
```

Thanks guys, appreciate it a lot

-Shardj

Comment: try passing the `$_POST` values as parameters to the `setVariables` function, there could be an issue with your functions scope.

Comment: In `setMessage`, you're replacing the `Name: ...` stuff with `$_POST['Message']`. Did you really mean to do that? `setVariables` already put `$_POST['message']` in there.

Comment: @MarkHill `$_POST` is a super-global, it's available in all scopes.

Comment: this is true, but I've had strange issues happen with the global variables before, it's always worth looking into.

Comment: And remember, `$_POST['Message']` (with capital M) is not the same as `$_POST['message']` (small m).

Comment: @MarkHill No it isn't worth looking into, it's a total waste of time.

Comment: What's the purpose of lines like `$name;` and `$email;` before the `if(isset)` lines?

Comment: `setVariables` reports an error if any of the parameters is set but null. Why doesn't it report an error if the parameter isn't set?

Comment: Your code looks good, I guess the problem is on $msg content, try sending a very simple email and see if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of this line:

```
$msg = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Message']));
```

It's overwriting `$msg` with the contents of a nonexistent parameter. It already contains the message text, which was in `$posted[3]`.

Comment: Make sure you have `error_reporting(E_ALL)` enabled. You would have gotten a warning about the undefined index `Message`, and that might have saved you lots of headache.

Answer (score -2):

It's your variable scope.  $name withing setVariables()

```
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    if (strlen($name) < 1) {$name = "ERROR - name is null";}

    $email=$_POST['email'];
    if (strlen($email)  < 1) {$email = "ERROR - email is null";}

    $enquiry=$_POST['enquiry'];
    if (strlen($enquiry)  < 1) {$enquiry = "ERROR - enquiry is null";}

    $posted = array($name,$email,$enquiry,$message);

    $msg = setMessage($posted);
    $result = sendMail($msg);
    userFeedback($result);
```

Comment: What scope problem? He never uses `$name` outside the function.

Comment: @Misunderstood, would you elaborate on this answer just a bit more to clarify.

Comment: Where have you set `$posted` in your answer?

Comment: @Misunderstood no he's not, there hasn't been one edit to his code

Comment: @MarkHill  I don't need to argue.  The code changed.